# Question regarding the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

**Every non-constant polynomial in** $\mathbb C[x]$ **has a complex root**

To  prove  this  we  first  consider  a  polynomial  with  complex  coefficients $f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+.......a_{n}x^{n}$  and  its  conjugate  polynomial $\bar f(x)=\bar a_{0}+ \bar a_{1}x+\bar a_{2}x^{2}+....+\bar a_{n}x^{n}$

Then  we  find $$f(x)\bar f(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$$  Then  it  says

*$f(x)$* *has* *a* *complex*  *root* *iff* *$f(x)\bar f(x)$*  *has* *a* *complex* *root*
Now  if  $f(x)$  has  a  complex  root  then  definitely  $f(x)\bar f(x)$  has  that  complex  number  as  its  root   but  I  am  stuck with  the  reverse .

Then  there   is  another  problem.  Proving  the  above ensures  that  *It's*  *sufficient*  *to*  *prove*  *the*  *statement*  *for*  *real*  *polynomials*.

And  then  it  takes  the  polynomial $$f(x)=p(x)(x^{2}+1)$$  where $p(x)$  is  irreducible  over  $\mathbb R$ and  considers  the  *Galois* *group*  of  $f(x)$ .

I  cannot   understand  why  they  needed  to  take  a  product  of  two   irreducible   polynomials  instead  of  one polynomial  irreducible  in  $\mathbb R[x]$  or  at  what  step  of  this  proof  it  was  put  to  use.

Please  don't  mind  anybody, I  am  uploading  an  image   of  the  proof.  Please   help  me  understand  these  two  things   properly.

[image]

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: To have the machinery of splitting fields of polynomials over $\Bbb{R}$ available they need to make sure that the polynomial has coefficients in $\Bbb{R}$. In other words, the polynomial $f(x)$ may not have real coefficients, but the product $f(x)\overline{f}(x)$ definitely does! The point of it having complex zeros is secondary to the need to get a polynomial with real coefficients.

Comment: And the multiplication with $x^2+1$ ensures that the splitting field contains $\mathbb{C}$. Also, $\bar{f}(z) = 0 \iff f(\bar{z}) = 0$.

Comment: About the first question: $f(x)\bar f(x)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)=0$ (done) or $\bar f(x)=0$ (i.e. $f(\bar x)=0$ (done)).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the homomorphism $\varphi\colon\mathbb{C}[x]\to\mathbb{C}[x]$ defined by $\varphi(a)=\bar{a}$ for $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\varphi(x)=x$. It is clear that $\varphi\circ\varphi$ is the identity, so $\varphi$ is an automorphism. In particular, since having a root is equivalent to being divisible by a degree one polynomial, $f\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ has a root if and only if $\varphi(f)$ has a root; note that $\varphi(f)=\bar{f}$ according to your notation.

If $f$ has a root, then clearly $f(x)\bar{f}(x)$ has a root. If $f(x)\bar{f}(x)$ has a root, then either $f$ has a root or $\bar{f}$ has a root; in the latter case also $f$ has a root.

Clearly $\overline{f(x)\bar{f}(x)}=f(x)\bar{f}(x)$, so every coefficient of $f(x)\bar{f}(x)$ is real.

Finally, considering the splitting field $E$ of $(x^2+1)p(x)$ ensures that $\mathbb{C}$ is (isomorphic to a) subfield of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, if $z_0$ is a root of $f(x)\bar{f}(x)$, $f(z_0)\bar{f}(z_0) = 0$ which means $f(z_0)\overline{f(\bar{z_0})} = 0$ .

thus either $f(z_0) = 0$ or $f(\bar{z_0}) = 0$ (in both case $f$ admits a complex root).

So we can conclude that if $f(x)\bar{f}(x)$ has a complex root, then $f(x)$ has a complex root.

For the second question. $\mathbb{C}$ is the splitting field of $x^2 + 1$ over $\mathbb{R}$ so in the answer $x^2 + 1$ is multiplied to make sure that $E$ "contains" $\mathbb{C}$($\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $E$).

Comment: Hey @corindo ,  there  is  still  something  I  do  not  understand . $|f(z_{0})|^{2} |f(\bar z_{0})|^{2}=0$  will  mean either $|f(z_{0})|=0$   or  $|f(\bar z_{0})|=0$ . How can  we  conclude  that  it  is  $f(z_{0}=0$ $?$

Comment: @user118494 : you're right, I didn't finish the proof. The aim is to prove that $f$ has a root (either $z_0$ or $\bar{z_0}$）.